# Gnome Night Light keeps reseting after 5 seconds

Tags: gnome

Ok, this is driving me nuts (Gnome 3.32.1)

No matter how I configure Night Light (fixed or automatic hours), the display is always too blue. Whenever I go in the config of nightlight and change the color, it turns to my target value and without fail, back to the previous value. This resting blue value is definitely not the one I selected because even when I click to the left of my target value, the screen gets redder. Its almost as if Night Light is off, but it appears turned on.

I've even tried changing the value through dconf-editor and no joy.

Is there an automatic script that does something with the Night Light in the background every 5 seconds?

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Any update to this?

Comment: sorry, no updates yet, I switched to the sunrise schedule and while not ideal, it seems to be more stable

Comment: What do you mean by "sunrise schedule"? Is this a different app?

Comment: the exact name is "Sunrise to Sunset", this way you let Gnome automatically set the interval based on calendar and approx geographical location